# MySQL IF/CASE syntax that calls different SELECT statements

Tags: mysql

I'm having problems using MySQL's `IF` or `CASE` syntax

The procedure goes something like this:

I have a PHP project that calls a MySQL query, let's say PHP passes variable `X`.

If `X` is not `0` then it should perform a query something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id = X
```

But if `X` is `0`. then it should perform a query to just select all records:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

I don't want to have the condition in PHP which calls a different MySQL query based on the result of the condition in PHP. I want the if / else condition to be performed inside the SQL query based on the variable passed `X`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `$x` is derived from your PHP, then:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE IF($x=0, 1, id=$x)
```

(it's to show general idea, you'll have to handle injections e t.c. by yourself)

*Edit*

I've  found nice code in another answer here. So I was curious - which is faster? Now I'm 'happy' that mine is that as well:

My version:

```
mysql> select @@version;
+-----------+
| @@version |
+-----------+
| 5.5.27    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, test data:

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+-------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+
|  1 | f     |
|  3 | t     |
|  4 | s     |
+----+-------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

And tests:

**First: IF comparison**

```
mysql> select @x;
+------+
| @x   |
+------+
| t    |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select benchmark(1E7, if(@x=0, 1, title=@x)) from test;
+---------------------------------------+
| benchmark(1E7, if(@x=0, 1, title=@x)) |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     0 |
|                                     0 |
|                                     0 |
+---------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (1.66 sec)

mysql> set @x=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select benchmark(1E7, if(@x=0, 1, title=@x)) from test;
+---------------------------------------+
| benchmark(1E7, if(@x=0, 1, title=@x)) |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     0 |
|                                     0 |
|                                     0 |
+---------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (1.85 sec)
```

**Second, OR comparison**

```
mysql> select @x;
+------+
| @x   |
+------+
|    0 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select benchmark(1E7, title = @X or @X = 0) from test;
+--------------------------------------+
| benchmark(1E7, title = @X or @X = 0) |
+--------------------------------------+
|                                    0 |
|                                    0 |
|                                    0 |
+--------------------------------------+
3 rows in set, 65535 warnings (17.31 sec)
```

-ok, that was because of type-casting. Fixing:

```
mysql> set @x='0';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select benchmark(1E7, title = @X or @X = '0') from test;
+----------------------------------------+
| benchmark(1E7, title = @X or @X = '0') |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                      0 |
|                                      0 |
|                                      0 |
+----------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (5.78 sec)
```

And, finally, non-zero:

```
mysql> set @x='t';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select benchmark(1E7, title = @X or @X = '0') from test;
+----------------------------------------+
| benchmark(1E7, title = @X or @X = '0') |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                      0 |
|                                      0 |
|                                      0 |
+----------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (4.92 sec)
```

**Conclusion**

`IF` comparison seems to be much more faster in this case, than `OR` (about 3 times for 1E7 benchmark iterations)

Comment: can you explain what the 1 means? yes, there are no problems with the injections, just SQL statement

Comment: 1 means that it will be `WHERE 1`, i.e. always true for any row - i.e. entire table because any row will match

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE $x = 0 or id = $x
```

Comment: down voter, care to comment? this is one of the nicest queries speed wise I have seen posted.

Comment: That wasn't my downvote, but I think that was because there's no `X` column (but there's $x from PHP)

Comment: I thought that was obvious :)

Comment: @Alma Didn't say it was 'fastest', but certainly more extendable for additional conditions :)

Comment: @Alma however, $x = 0 or id = $x is indeed faster than _equivalent_ if()

Comment: @kgu87 but we're talking about this question, right? And you need to provide certain benchmark tests to be sure that it is so with equivalent if

Comment: with @x = 0, select benchmark(1E7, @x = 0 or title = @x) from test; gives 0.83sec and select benchmark(1E7, if(@x=0, 1, title=@x)) from test; gives 0.98sec. The reason your test was different was casting @x = 0 to @x = '0' which is not comparable to if(@x=0)