# mysql: write query with if in where part

Tags: mysql

i have this table:

```
(`id`, `name`, `type`, `price`) 
(1, 'cats', 1, 12.25),
(2, 'dogs', 0, 11.35),
(3, 'house', 1, 7.25),
(4, 'cats2', 2, 5.26);
```

I need select all data, but if type is 1, i need get items witch price is more than 10.
I create this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `items` 
WHERE IF(TYPE =  "1", price > 10, 1 = 1)
```

Works well, but maybe possible write much smarter or in other way?
Maybe don't need "1 = 1"?.

I would like to know your advice, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `1=1` is senseless, but your `IF` is not. You can use just `1`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `items` 
WHERE IF(TYPE =  "1", price > 10, 1)
```

-since MySQL evaluates expression as bool (actually, int) - and so `1` means 'true'.

But on the other hand, there's logic equivalent for your condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `items` 
WHERE `price`>10 OR `type`!="1"
```

However, I've faced such case in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19400492/2637490) and, after some researching, I've discovered that `IF` is faster, even if it looks more complicated.